# Creating parent/child drop down lists using complex json object and knockout bindings

Tags: knockout.js

I have a json object that has sites and clients for the sites. One site 
can have many clients.

I know how to populate the site drop down list box (parent) using 
knockout bindings. However, I cannot figure out how to populate the 
clients drop down list (child) when the onchange happens in the parent 
drop down list.

I would appreciate if someone with more experience could change my 
code below to show me how to achieve the master/child drop down list 
functionality.

Cheers

C

```
    var posterArray = ([
                           { SiteId: 1,
                             SiteName: "Mail",
                             ClientSite:[
                                { ClientId: 1, ClientName: "Mail Client A" }, { ClientId: 1, ClientName: "Mail Client B"}]  
                           },

                           { SiteId: 2,
                             SiteName: "DSAC",
                             ClientSite:
                                { ClientId: 1, ClientName: "DSAC Client A" }
                           }
    ]);


    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        // Poster
        self.PosterList = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
        self.PosterListEnable = false;

        self.refreshPosterList = function () {
            var data = [];
            if (posterArray.length == 0) {
                data = [{ SiteId: 'No Posters', SiteName: 'No Posters'}];
            } else if (posterArray.length == 1) {
                data = posterArray;
            } else {
                data = [{ SiteId: 'Select a Poster', SiteName: 'Select a Poster'}];
                data.push.apply(data, posterArray);
            }

            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, null, self.PosterList);
            self.refreshClientList();
        };


        //Client
        self.ClientList = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
        self.refreshClientList = function () {

        };

    };

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    $(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        viewModel.refreshPosterList();
    });

</script>
<fieldset class="SearchFilter">
    <legend>Search Filter</legend>
    <div class="SearchItem">
        <span>Poster:</span>
        <select id="dllPoster" data-bind="foreach: PosterList, disable:PosterList().length <= 1" onchange="viewModel.refreshClientList();">
            <option data-bind="text: SiteName, attr:{value:SiteId}"></option>
        </select>
        <select id="ddlClient" data-bind="with: PosterList.ClientSite ">
            <option data-bind="text: ClientName, attr:{value:ClientId}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Knockout has a specific binding for drop down lists.  Take look at the "options" binding:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Here's a jsFiddle of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/9QVw9/

Comment: Hi ckal, Thanks for your reply and help. I will read the post you suggested and look at the jsFiddle.

Comment: Hi ckal, can you please explain to me how the value: selectedPoster bind works? Your not assigning any value to it. Where do you set it to the selected value in the select? '<select id="dllPoster" data-bind="options: PosterList, optionsText: 'SiteName', value: selectedPoster, disable:PosterList().length <= 1" ></select>
        <select id="ddlClient" data-bind="options: selectedPoster().ClientSite, optionsText: 'ClientName', value: selectedClient">'            
        </select>

Comment: Hi, I am trying to add logic to my optionsCaption for the child select but it not working

Comment: <select id="Select2" data-bind="options: ( selectedPoster().ClientSite!=undefined ||  selectedPoster().ClientSite!=null)? selectedPoster().ClientSite :'', optionsText:( selectedPoster().ClientSite!=undefined ||  selectedPoster().ClientSite!=null)? 'ClientName':'', value: ( selectedPoster().ClientSite!=undefined ||  selectedPoster().ClientSite!=null)? 'selectedClient':'',  optionsCaption: ( selectedPoster().ClientSite==undefined)?'No Clients':( selectedPoster().ClientSite.length==1)?'':'Select a Client'">            
        </select>

Comment: How do I add the id of the object to the value property of the options?